# How to wisely redirect after successful ajax login?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a method calling ajax and after success I need to redirect to another page.

I think when ajax call ends my URL is by default changed, ending with my username and password which I have posted in the ajax call.

How to wisely handle this? I am not in a situation to remove async false and I know I can send password and username using ajax given keys.

```js
function Login() {
    var model = { user_Name: $("#username").val(), Password: $("#password").val() };
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'http://localhost:51525/api/HomeApi/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Function is successfully returned now redirect");

            //how to redirect??
            //window.location.href = 'http://localhost:51525/user/';
            //window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","User")';  
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: just use window.location

Comment: *"I think when ajax call ends My url is by DEFAULT changed ending with my username and password which i have posted in ajax call."* No, it isn't. Ajax calls don't change the location of the page you're on. What, **specifically**, happened when you tried the things commented out in your code? `window.location.href = 'http://localhost:51525/user/';` works (which you can also just write as `location.href = 'http://localhost:51525/user/';` or even `location = 'http://localhost:51525/user/';` or, if the page is on `http://localhost:51525`, just `location = '/user/';`)

Comment: AND THIS all is NOT WORKING. THIS is the concern man

Comment: I think you are using a form to login. When you login the form gets submitted by may be `get method` and you may be under the impression that `Login()` method is called.
Post the HTML code as well.

Comment: How do you call `Login()`. Possibly not preventing a form submit here?

Comment: using onclik  on form button

Comment: Show us. If you don't prevent the default form submit the page will reload based on action in form

Comment: Why are you using AJAX for login ? its not proper way to use ajax anyway use @url.action whenever possible this will help later while hosting the app and you dont need to change the href each time

Comment: Define `action="http://localhost:51525/api/HomeApi/"` and `method=POST` in form element itself. No need to write separate AJAX method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your url shows the username and password is because you are triggering the form submit with the default method="GET".

There are lots of alternatives.  E.G.:

Return false from your Login.  This will disable the form submit.

```
function Login() {
    //Your code...
    return false;
}
```

Or

Don't use ajax at all, and use a normal form post:

```
<form method="POST" action="/api/HomeApi/">
```

---

Additionally, there are other ways a user might submit the form so `<form onsubmit="Login()">` is probably better than `<input onclick="Login()">`